# Highlight points on click with shiny and ggvis

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I am trying to highlight (ex. stroke) points on my scatterplot by clicking. So for example I have a tooltip and if the tooltip gives me some important information I want to mark this point. Is there something already available?

I already played a little bit with two tooltips, one prints some information, the other appends the id of the point to a list and I try to add this information to the data and create a new graph with highlighting the ids. Not very handy.

Here is a minimal example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), id=letters[1:10])
server <- function(input, output) {
  movie_tooltip <- function(x) {
    x$id
  }
  vis <- reactive({
    df %>%
      ggvis(~x, ~y) %>% 
      layer_points(key := ~id)  %>%
      add_tooltip(movie_tooltip, "hover")
  })
  vis %>% bind_shiny("plot1") 
  observe({
    if(input$myBtn > 0){
      stopApp()
    }
  })
}
ui <- fluidPage(
  ggvisOutput("plot1"),
  actionButton("myBtn", "Press ME!")
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How can I highlight or mark some of the dots?

**UPDATE:**

I got partly some results which I wanted to present so far. I can highlight a dot but I would also like to "unhighlight" them again on click.

I added a second add_tooltip function and some reactiveValues but it is not possible for me to switch back to unlabeled. It gets in kind of a loop and never stops...

Here is my updated example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), id=letters[1:10])

server <- function(input, output) {
  movie_tooltip <- function(x) {
    x$id
  }
  movie_tooltip2 <- function(x) {
    i <- which(df$id == x$id)
#     ifelse(values$stroke[i] == 'Yes',
#            values$stroke[i] <- 'No',
#            values$stroke[i] <- 'Yes')
    values$stroke[i] <- "Yes"
    return(NULL)
  }
  values <- reactiveValues(stroke=rep('No',nrow(df)))
  vis <- reactive({
    df %>%
      ggvis(~x, ~y, stroke = ~values$stroke) %>% 
      layer_points(key := ~id)  %>%
      add_tooltip(movie_tooltip, "hover")  %>%
      add_tooltip(movie_tooltip2, "click")
  })
  vis %>% bind_shiny("plot1") 
}
ui <- fluidPage(
  ggvisOutput("plot1")
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If I uncomment the three #comments, and comment out this line`# values$stroke[i] <- "Yes"`, I stuck in a loop and don't understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what is happening is that by making a change to a reactive object inside of `tooltip()` you are invalidating the tooltip itself, and so you're stuck in an infinite loop.

To get around this use `isolate()` around the change to the values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), id=letters[1:10])

server <- function(input, output) {
  movie_tooltip <- function(x) {
    x$id
  }
  movie_tooltip2 <- function(x) {
    i <- which(df$id == x$id)
    isolate(values$stroke[i] <- ifelse(values$stroke[i] == 'Yes',
                values$stroke[i] <- 'No',
                values$stroke[i] <- 'Yes'))
    return(NULL)
  }
  values <- reactiveValues(stroke=rep('No',nrow(df)))
  vis <- reactive({
    df %>%
      ggvis(~x, ~y, stroke = ~values$stroke) %>% 
      layer_points(key := ~id)  %>%
      add_tooltip(movie_tooltip, "hover")  %>%
      add_tooltip(movie_tooltip2, "click")
  })
  vis %>% bind_shiny("plot1") 
}
ui <- fluidPage(
  ggvisOutput("plot1")
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my problem. I also tried to use isolate but obviously in the wrong way. Now it is working.